# Javascript UC and UC properties

Tags: javascript, user-controls, genexus

I have this UC:

```
this.show = function()
{

    ...

    var myvar = "Text of the var."  

    this.Property1 = myvar + "1";
    this.Property2 = myvar + "2";

    this.FontSize = 40;


    ///UserCodeRegionEnd: (do not remove this comment.)
}
```

And this event in the UC:

[image]

And I get this result:

[image]

So my question is, why the properties do not have the value I assign in the method show()?

Comment: This should be working. Can you upload your web application to the cloud using "Deploy to cloud" option? (see http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Deploy+to+cloud%3A+Step+by+Step, for more information).

Paste the URL in the comments and I'll take a closer look at the problem.

Comment: The URL http://trialapps3.genexus.com/Id899a095c574c049b25f760a574de3016/execute.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are expecting the values of the properties to be avaiblable when the page is loaded for the first time. The values of the properties modified in the show method are available after a user event is fired (for example, Enter).

To solve the problem, insert a button in your web form, bind it to the Enter event, and move the code inside the Load event to the Enter event.

Comment: I tried to put everything inside a Enter event and it works when I press enter. Thanks! I had no idea that this was the problem.
But the problem is that when I press enter the page is refreshed, and I don't want to refresh the page. There is another way to do it? Basically I want to pass some javascript values to the ide Genexus variables of the webpanel, and then store the values in the database. This should be simple, but I don't know how to do it in Genexus.

Comment: Another annoying little problem is why the value of the property1 is not appearing.

Comment: Check the 'Property1' property definition. Make sure the Id and Name elements have the same value in the property definition.

Comment: Regarding your question asking whether there's another way of reading the values of the properties, the short answer is no. The only way to send data from the browser to the server is by firing a user event. Think of user control's properties as hidden variables in the web form.

Comment: Do you know where is the specification of the language used inside the events?